# BASH text edit with seq

Tags: bash, sequence

With this I can **callmyscrip.sh 100** and this will print 100 rows with the content generated by seq, but what's the best way to separate the content `TEXT="xxx yyy ${this}"` for readability with a variable?

```
#!/bin/bash
howmanytimes=$1
for this in $(seq -w ${howmanytimes}); do echo " /
-- ${this}

"; done
```

this instead would not work as $this isn't replaced:

```
#!/bin/bash
howmanytimes=$1
TEXT="THIS WOULD NOT WORK: ${this}"
for this in $(seq -w ${howmanytimes}); do echo ${TEXT} ; done
export $TEXT
```

Comment: What means 'content' ? Please, elaborate.

Comment: [Don't use UPPER case variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seq(1)` is nonstandard, inefficient and useless.

Check http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Loops

With [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh):

```
#!/bin/ksh

txt='this should work with int: '
for i in {0..$1}; do
    echo "$txt $i"
done
```

With [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
#!/bin/bash

txt='this should work with int: '
for ((i=0; i<=$1; i++)) {
    echo "$txt $i"
}
```

Comment: `seq` is **not** inefficient. `printf '%s' "$txt "; seq -s $'\n'"$txt " "$1"` is more efficient than using a C-style `for` loop in `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your dynamic text in a bash function:

```
#!/bin/bash

get_content() {
    echo "THIS WOULD WORK: $1"
}

how_many_times=$1

for i in $(seq -w ${how_many_times}); do
    echo "$(get_content $i)"
done
```

If you just need to output the content, can simplify it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

get_content() {
    echo "THIS WOULD WORK: $1"
}

how_many_times=$1

for i in $(seq -w ${how_many_times}); do
    get_content $i
done
```

Comment: `$( )` removes trailing carriage return. If you want to output without a newline on the end, you can do `echo -n "$(get_content $i)"` with the second version. Just use the second version, it's great.

Comment: avoid the use of `seq`. Check my answer

Comment: No need a function, a variable is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf` directly, and skip the loop entirely:

```
#!/bin/bash
howmanytimes=$1
text="This WILL work: %s"
printf "${text}\n" $(seq -w ${howmanytimes})
```

Note that `\n` needs to be added to the format string, since `printf` doesn't add a newline automatically like `echo` does. If you want additional newlines (like in the example), you can add them as either `\n` or actual newlines, in either the format variable or where it's used in the `printf` argument. Also, if you want to include a literal backslash or percent sign in the string, double it (i.e. `%%` to print `%`, or `\\` to print `\`).

BTW, since `printf` is a bash builtin, it's not subject to the normal argument list length limits, so this'll work even with very large numbers of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Check your script with shellcheck. `printf` is a simple template language. I could see:

```
#!/bin/bash
howmanytimes=$1
text="THIS WOULD WORK: %s"
for this in $(seq -w "${howmanytimes}"); do
   printf "$text" "$this"
done
```

You could use `envsubst` to replace environment, however in this case `printf` looks way clearer. Research quoting in shell.

```
#!/bin/bash
howmanytimes=$1
text='THIS WOULD WORK: ${THIS}'
for this in $(seq -w "${howmanytimes}"); do
   THIS="$this" envsubst <<<"$text"
done
```